# From SQL Server to google.map

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, location

We are using IMS tool, which is UI for insurance industry that talks to SQL Server and retrieves the data.

So, I don't have any access to this IMS tool, The third party company taking care of it.

When you look at the customer info in this tool, you are able to click on a button and it will take you to a google map.

[image]

My question, is this functionality configured in this tool itself? or there is a stored procedure in SQL Server database that pools somehow link and takes you to a google map?

Thanks

Comment: Why not ask the third party that is taking care of it?

Comment: In the app I am currently working on, the SQL stores the geolocation code, then the app calls a service that places the point on the map based on the type of geolocation code, whether its a point, street, city or zip.    But I am sure that there is a ton of ways to dos this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested, this is a simple example on how to create a HYPERLINK in Excel

Run this SQL, and paste the results into Excel  You will notice a cell value that reads "Show Map" ... just click on that

```
Declare @MyData table (CustID int,StreetAddress varchar(100),City varchar(50),State varchar(25),ZipCode varchar(25))
Insert into @MyData values 
(1,'114 Morgan St','Stamford','CT','06905')

Select *
      ,MapURL_Excel  = '=HYPERLINK("https://www.google.com/maps/place/'+StreetAddress+'+'+City+',+'+State+'+'+ZipCode+'","Show Map")'
      ,MapURL_General= 'https://www.google.com/maps/place/'+StreetAddress+'+'+City+',+'+State+'+'+ZipCode
 from @MyData
```

> **Updated.  It requires +'s instead of spaces**

Comment: I should add that I know nothing about Roambi reporting

Comment: I dont know much about Roambi reporting as well. But my boss loves it how it can be interactive on his iPhone. So I have to learnt it ))
Thanks for code

Answer (score 0):

> **Not meant to be an answer.**

Google offers some TREMENDOUS API's.   They make it very easy to map and/or visualize data.

Depending on the call, you can supply an address or even Lat/Lng

Below is an image illustrating a data-grid which is easily linked to google maps.

[image]

Comment: Are you looking to map a single address or a series?  To do a series, it is best to store the Lat/Lng in the database

Comment: You do need a little HTML/JavaScript in your tool belt.    Take a peek at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation

Comment: I have an address column. How can I store Lat/Lng in a database? Can it be generated based on address?

Comment: you can simply have a url with the address in it.  For example:  https://www.google.com/maps/place/114+Morgan+St,+Stamford,+CT+06905

Comment: For the record, Not my address, I am in Rhode Island  :)

Comment: So what would be my first step? To generate column with URL addresses ?

Comment: What is your environment?  Web?  Access?  Visual Fox Pro?

Comment: SQL Server 2012 stores the data. Then data will be retrieved in Excel and loaded into Roambi reporting tool.

Comment: Added a second answer